# JAX-RS Rest service giving "HTTP Status 404 – Not Found" error tomcat while accessing in docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, jax-rs, dockerfile, tomcat8

I am having an issue with accessing rest service with docker as  http://192.168.99.100:8080/rest/clients.I am getting *HTTP Status 404 – Not Found*. While without docker I have access the rest service like http://localhost:8080/rest/clients.Please anybody helps on my issue.

here is my docker-compose file,

```
version: '3'

services:  
  tomcat:
    container_name: tomcat_docker
    image: tomcat:latest
    environment:
      - TOMCAT_USERNAME=admin
      - TOMCAT_PASSWORD=secret
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - /docker/AW317/TaskmanagerDocker-03212018/tomcat-users.xml:/usr/local/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml
      - /docker/AW317/TaskmanagerDocker-03212018/TaskManager.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/TaskManager.war
    command: ["/usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh", "run"]
    links:
      - db:mysql
  db:
    container_name: mysql_docker
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - 53306:3306
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
```

I have tried to overwrite tomcat-users.xml but won't help.
can any anybody help me on this issue? what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just overwrite context.xml file in docker using volume path and issue resolved,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Context antiResourceLocking="true" privileged="true" >
 <!--<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />-->
</Context>
```

Now I can access the rest service.

Edit:

you can overwrite context.xml in the docker-compose file as bellow,

```
volumes:
      - <path to docker whaere it is located>/context.xml:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml
```

you can put context.xml file in your project directory.

Comment: Is it possible to explain how to override the context.xml of docker?

Comment: @Arashsoft yes just write this command to the docker-compose file.for that see my edited answer.